# Modify newly created file which my teammate hasn't pushed to git

Tags: git

If I would like to edit a newly created file from my teammate, what should I do? If I download the file directly from the server, git will think that all of the content from the file is written by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to have your teammate commit this file, push it (doesn't have to be on the master/main branch - any branch would do), and then fetch this branch, add your changes as an additional commit on top of it, and push it back so that your teammate can fetch your changes.